# Determine when leaving a view controller that it's not a segue

Tags: ios

I'm trying to save some data upon user leaving this specific view controller (either by hitting nav back button or different tab bar button or exiting the app). However, there is one segue going forward, in this case I don't want to save the data yet, it will get saved on the next view controller with additional data.

How can I determine in `viewWillDisappear:` (or anywhere else) that user is leaving the view controller, but differentiate that it is not through the segue? I've looked at `self.isBeingDismissed()` and `self.isMovingFromParentViewController()` and I can't seem figure out a good solution. Any insight is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try this method instead of viewWillDisappear-

```
fun willMoveToParentViewController(parent : UIViewController?)
{
    super.willMoveToParentViewController(parent);
    if parent == nil {
        //This means the current controller is getting popped out of the nav stack
    }
}
```

Documentation:

> Called just before the view controller is added or removed from a
>   container view controller.

Since navigation controller is a container controller, when it removes the top most controller, it should call this method with parent value as nil.

HTH